# rounded recyclerview with cardview item inside

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview, radius

I have rounded `RecyclerView` in top right and top left corner with `Drawable` file

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#eee"/>
</shape>
```

and use `CardView` as item for `RecyclerView`

problem is here that when I scroll `RecyclerView`, items come over on `RecyclerView` in corners.

can anyone tell me what is my mistake or show me how to fix this?

code of layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I expect see List Items comes under the `RecyclerView` in top left and top right corner

but see this [image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwz3J.jpg)

Comment: can you post your layout xml file?

Comment: i added layout xml file code

Comment: what do you expect to see ?

Comment: I expect see List Items comes under the RecyclerView in top left and top right corner